# How to show pushviewcontroller on first application launch?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults, pushviewcontroller

I'm checking with `NSUserDefault` if it is the first time app is loaded.
If is the first time I must push a viewcontroller to a specific view.
I do the same action and it works, but the first time app load don't.

Here's my code:

```
SettingsViewController *viewSet = [[SettingsViewController alloc] 
                                   initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" 
                                   bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.settingViewController = viewSet;
[viewSet release];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:self.settingViewController animated:YES];   
settingViewController.title =@"Impostazioni";
```

I receive a sigkill some instruction after pushing the viewController.

Maybe the problem is that it's in `viewDidAppear`?
I must check there because if is not the first time I must load some other userdefaults values.

EDIT:

I've found the trouble (some bad values passed at `NSUserDefaults`).
Now my controller is pushed but I don't see any button to pop of this viewcontroller....

Comment: You can pass nil as the second parameter if the nib is in the main bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to push a different view the first time your app starts?

What is the problem? The code above will push a 'SettingViewController' onto the navigation stack when run.

Comment: the problem is that apps crash if it's the first time, without error message in console.

Comment: find my trouble (some bad value passed at NSUserDefaults).Now my controller is pushed but i don't see any button to pop of this viewcontroller....